# Table column width shrinks when fixed position is set (Chrome only)

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table

The cells in the table fit the text plus some extra space, appx 4 spaces or so.  I have the second, similar table, with `position:fixed;` and it shrinks the extra space around the text to zero, so the two tables are no longer the same width.

What I need is a header "table" that has the same width as the actual table, but is fixed to the same screen position

Edit:  This is in Chrome only.

Edit:  To reproduce the problem, copy the following code into an html document and open it with chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="http://bookyoursite.com/assets/admin.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>



<table style="position:fixed;background-color:white;top:0;left:100px;">
        <tr> 
            <td width="200px;">
                Park Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Park Viewed
            </td>
            <td>
                Book Now Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Website Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Call Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Email Button
            </td>
            <td>
                Book Now Call Button
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:20px">
    <tr> 
        <td width="200px;">
            Park Name
        </td>
        <td>
            Park Viewed
        </td>
        <td>
            Book Now Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Website Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Call Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Email Button
        </td>
        <td>
            Book Now Call Button
        </td>
    </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                Camp Hatteras RV Resort and Campground
            </td>
            <td>
                    1
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This has something to do with the fact that the long park name wraps around to the next line

Comment: what exactly do you mean by it  being fixed to the same screen position?

Comment: As you scroll down the table, the title bar of the table (which is a different fixed-position table) will stay at the top of the window

Comment: so you want the table header to remain static?

Comment: yes, that's not the trouble though.  The problem is that the header table is not the same width as the actual table.  See edit in the OP for the problem

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no space around text in table cells - they are automatically expanded just enough to accommodate the content (until table container boundary is reached, after which content may wrap). Sounds like in your non-header table the cells are expanded by content of cells in some rows (where text is longer than column title). If you want columns in both tables to have equal width, easiest solution is to specify all widths explicitly.

Note: avoid using `width` attribute of `<td>`, use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L7tzB/

CODE:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center" style="text-align:  center;">
<tr>
    <td width="200px;">Park Name</td>
    <td>Park Viewed</td>
    <td>Book Now Button</td>
    <td>Website Button</td>
    <td>Call Button</td>
    <td>Email Button</td>
    <td>Book Now Call Button</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center" style="text-align: center;">
<tr>
    <td width="200px;">Park Name</td>
    <td>Park Viewed</td>
    <td>Book Now Button</td>
    <td>Website Button</td>
    <td>Call Button</td>
    <td>Email Button</td>
    <td>Book Now Call Button</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Camp Hatteras RV Resort and Campground</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, see my edit for the reproducible problem